# Determining parity of the multiplicative inverse?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, parity

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field of characteristic $p > 2$, for a fixed $p$. I will consider only prime fields, not $GF(p^n)$. Represent the $p$ elements of the field as integers $\{0,1,\ldots p-1\}$.
Now lets define the "positive elements" as $\{0,2,4\ldots p-1\}$ and "negative elements" as $\{1,3,5\ldots p-2\}$.

(In other words the sign bit is the least significant bit of the integers's binary representation).

I was wondering if there is a way to determine the sign of $\frac{u}{v}$ given $u,v \in \mathbb{F}_p$ without computing the multiplicative inverse?
Or in other words, is there a faster way than computing $uv^{p-2}$ to determine the sign bit of $\frac{u}{v}$?

(Besides using Extended Euclidean algorithm for computing the inversion, which is faster than $v^{p-2}$).

Comment: For $p>2$, digits are larger than bits, and whether a digit is even or odd furthermore depends on what representation (e.g. least nonnegative vs. least absolute value) is used.

Comment: @ccorn I meant if you take the field element and consider its binary representation as a number $< p$, then the sign is the least significant bit.

Comment: For $p=5$ you have that $4$ is even, and $9$is odd: but they are the same element! So what is your definition of parity?

Comment: What do you mean by "positive" and "negative"? Every element in a finite field can be represented by both a negative and a positive integer. For example, $5 \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: Represent the $p$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ by integers $\{0,1,…p−1\}$, parity of an element is then the parity of the corresponding integer. The odd ones are considered "negative", the even ones are considered "positive".

Comment: Extended Euclid's algorithm gives a faster way of calculating $1/v$ and hence also $u/v$ (in comparison to calculating $v^{p-2}$). But what's the point? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The origin of this problem comes from a cryptographic algorithm. Would be a long story, but basically $u$ and $v$ represent coordinates on an elliptic curve $C_1$. There is a birational map to another curve $C_2$, which is $(u,v) \mapsto (\frac{u}{v},\frac{u-1}{u+1})$. The signature is formed by only the second coordinate on $C_2$ and the parity of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not consistent; you cannot think of them as being positive and negative in this way and get something meaningful.  For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, you have $1$ as negative and $2$ as positive.  So $2^{-1} = 2$ is positive, and $1^{-1} = 1$ is negative.  In $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, $3$ is negative and $3^{-1} = 2$ is positive.

The real problem is that if your finite field does not have prime order, you cannot even use this definition of positive and negative for elements not in the base field.

A more common thing is to consider the elements that are squares in the field as being "positive" and the nonsquares as "negative". Then you have that the inverse of a nonsquare is a nonsquare, inverse of a square is a square.

Comment: I only consider prime fields, not extensions. Well, to be more specific, I am only interested in a fixed $p$, therefore only one specific prime field. If the definition is not consistent across different fields, I don't care. But still, I presume even for fixed $p$ there is no way of determining the parity of the inverse (knowing the parity of the element) other than actually computing the inverse.

Comment: Yes, it would be an option if my prime wasn't 256-bits :) But anyway, all I needed was reassurance that my assumption about always needing to compute the inverse to get its parity was not flawed. Thanks!